# How to align multiple time series (of different dates) in relative time and set an event (b) as time 0 for all time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a timeseries measuring a variable "a" frequently (in reality, data every other minute) and b as an event (for example an earthquake). I want to see how the event affects the timeseries value immediately prior and after.

Therefore, for every event b I want to create a time series in relative time and align the time series around the event b (so the starting point would be b as time 0) and a values before that time would be labels -1, -2 and after b 1, 2.. etc. For this example just have 3 values before and after the event. At timepoints: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ,3

How can I best do it?

I have tried to convert them all to relative time but cant seem to make them align around b with time 0, since the frequency of observation differ between the ID. (optimally I would like to observe what happens 24h before and 24 h after the event b. And in my data b might sometime be followed by 2h of data and then nothing - for the nodata I would like it to be NA)

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Date <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-10-01 08:00", "2019-10-01 09:00", "2019-10-01 10:00", "2019-10-01 11:00",
                     "2019-10-01 12:00","2019-10-01 13:00","2019-10-01 14:00","2019-10-01 15:00"
                     ,"2012-01-01 07:00","2012-01-01 08:00","2012-01-01 09:00","2012-01-01 10:00"
                     ,"2012-01-01 11:00","2012-01-01 12:00","2012-01-01 13:00","2012-01-01 14:00",
                     "2014-08-12 13:00","2014-08-12 14:00","2014-08-12 15:00","2014-08-12 16:00",
                     "2014-08-12 17:00","2014-08-12 18:00","2014-08-12 19:00","2014-08-12 20:00"))
Name <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a","a","a","a","a", "b", "a", "a","a","b")
Value <- c(12, 14, 15, 15, 15, 13, 14, 26, 54, 50, 64, 53, 63, 64 ,2, 12, 24, 53, 64, 75, 2, 13, 13, 12)

df <- data.frame(ID, Date, Name, Value)
```

Expected result:

```
ID1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Date1 <- c("-6", "-5", "-4", "-3",
                     "-2","-1","0","1"
                     ,"-4","-3","-2","-1"
                     ,"0","1","2","3",
                     "-3","-2","-1","0",
                     "1","2","3","0")
Name1 <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a","a","a","a","a", "b", "a", "a","a","b")
Value1 <- c(12, 14, 15, 15, 15, 13, 14, 26, 54, 50, 64, 53, 63, 64 ,2, 12, 24, 53, 64, 75, 2, 13, 13, 12)

df_exp <- data.frame(ID1, Date1, Name1, Value1)
```

Although - I would like the "b" at the end of ID=3 to also become a stand alone time series with ID=3 and the values -3,-2,1,0, NA, NA, NA..
 --- I cant seem to extract another b from the same id into its own time series.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach using semi-join using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
i <- df[df[Name=="b", .(Date=Date+60*60*(-3:3)), .(ID, d=Date)], 
    on=.(ID, Date), which=TRUE, nomatch=0L]
df[i]
```

output:

```
    ID                Date Name Value
 1:  1 2019-10-01 11:00:00    a    15
 2:  1 2019-10-01 12:00:00    a    15
 3:  1 2019-10-01 13:00:00    a    13
 4:  1 2019-10-01 14:00:00    b    14
 5:  1 2019-10-01 15:00:00    a    26
 6:  2 2012-01-01 08:00:00    a    50
 7:  2 2012-01-01 09:00:00    a    64
 8:  2 2012-01-01 10:00:00    a    53
 9:  2 2012-01-01 11:00:00    b    63
10:  2 2012-01-01 12:00:00    a    64
11:  2 2012-01-01 13:00:00    a     2
12:  2 2012-01-01 14:00:00    a    12
13:  3 2014-08-12 13:00:00    a    24
14:  3 2014-08-12 14:00:00    a    53
15:  3 2014-08-12 15:00:00    a    64
16:  3 2014-08-12 16:00:00    b    75
17:  3 2014-08-12 17:00:00    a     2
18:  3 2014-08-12 18:00:00    a    13
19:  3 2014-08-12 19:00:00    a    13
20:  3 2014-08-12 17:00:00    a     2
21:  3 2014-08-12 18:00:00    a    13
22:  3 2014-08-12 19:00:00    a    13
23:  3 2014-08-12 20:00:00    b    12
    ID                Date Name Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I can only see the original table in the output and not the output with aligned relative timescale - am I missing part of the output?

Comment: maybe i dun understand your problem well enough. i thought it matches your desired output? or maybe u can change the interval to plus minus 1 hour `*(-1:1)` to see if it works